# Writing XML line every frame in 30FPS

Tags: objective-c, xml, cocoa

Here is my code:

```
float timeInterval = 1 / [frameRateTextField floatValue];

        recordingTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:timeInterval
                                                          target:self
                                                        selector:@selector(recordingTimerSelector:)
                                                        userInfo:nil
                                                         repeats:YES];


- (void) recordingTimerSelector:(NSTimer*)timer{
    NSXMLElement *timecode = [[NSXMLElement alloc] initWithName:@"timecode"];
    [timecode setStringValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@,%@,%@,%@",[DMXChannelArray objectAtIndex:0], [DMXChannelArray objectAtIndex:1], [DMXChannelArray objectAtIndex:2], [DMXChannelArray objectAtIndex:3], [DMXChannelArray objectAtIndex:4]]];

    [root addChild:timecode];

    time = time + 1;
    [theRecordingTime setStringValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", time]];
}
```

Is this the best way to go about doing this? I'm basically making a "recorder" with a resolution of 30FPS. Is there a way to make it go with the actual time, instead of being a separate entity? It might make it more accurate. Like:

```
10:40:41.0 - record element
10:40:41.3 - record element
10:40:41.6 - record element
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why not abstract the data structure from the storage?  By that I mean to write to an efficient in memory data strucuture and then save to persistence later ...

Comment: Can you show an example?

Comment: No but you can avoid the string format with the "raw" data 30 times a second.  Store the raw data (the contribs to the formatted string) into an in memory ds (array of arrays??? don't know enough about your data) and then format string and write to xml when all done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [get the current number of seconds since the reference date by asking NSDate for it](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDate/timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate).

Get that time interval when you start your timer, and then every time it fires, and subtract the starting time interval from the current one to get the number of seconds since you started.